# Moving first elements before the last element in a list python

Tags: python, list, slice

Ok so I have a list and I want to move the number of elements at the start of the list before the last element in the list, where the last element represents the number of elements I need to move.
For example: `[2, 19, 6, 26, 1, 15, 12, 3]` and since the last element is a 3 the result would look like `[26, 1, 15, 12, 2, 19, 6, 3]`. Does anyone know how I can index the list in this way?

Comment: Is this a challenge? Is it for a productive work? Be aware that lists in Python (unlike lists in other languages) are not really optimized for shift/roll operations. As long as you have a limited use of this on small lists, why not? But if you want to embed such a thing in some heavier process, you should be aware of the complexity of these operations (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity ) and maybe rather focus on an index-based system. By indexing the start of your list rather than really building new lists you may keep a O(1) complexity rather than O(n).

Answer (score 3):

- To get the last item of the list, you would take the `-1`th index (`l[-1]`).
- To get the first `n` items of a list, slice from 0 to `n` (`l[0:n]`); Python will let you omit the initial `0`.
- To get the elements from `n` to the second last item in a list, slice from `n` to `-1` (`l[n:-1]`).

Putting this all together, you would use something like:

```
def move_items(lst):
    return lst[lst[-1]:-1] + lst[:lst[-1]] + [lst[-1]]
```

In action:

```
>>> def move_items(lst):
...     return lst[lst[-1]:-1] + lst[:lst[-1]] + [lst[-1]]
... 
>>> move_items([2,19,6,26,1,15,12,3])
[26, 1, 15, 12, 2, 19, 6, 3]
```

Comment: I think you could also do `lst[:lst[-1]]` instead of `lst[0:lst[-1]]`. I usually see the first form with the implicit `0`. (It's really tempting right now to say "saves 1 byte"... ;)

Comment: Just note that IN CASE the last number (the one that indicates how many will shift) is `>=` than the number of items in the list, it will add it again. EG: `move_items([2,19,6,26,1,15,12,8])` -> `[2, 19, 6, 26, 1, 15, 12, 8, 8]`.

Comment: Thank you door knob! It worked. The way I was going at it was finding the value of the bottom element using  bottom_card = deck_cards[-1] and using bottom_cards in all the values. But I guess this works too.

Answer (score 1):

```
def split(x):
  y = x[:]    # make a copy: not to harm incoming list
  numToMove = y.pop()
  return (numToMove, y[:numToMove], y[numToMove:])

a = [2, 19, 6, 26, 1, 15, 12, 3]
(num, head, tail) = split(a)
answer = tail + head + [num]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
l = [2, 19, 6, 26, 1, 15, 12, 3]
l2 = l[l[-1]:-1] + l[:l[-1]] + [l[-1]]
print l2
```

Answer (score 0):

A version using modulo that creates a single list without slicing:

```
def swap(l):
    i, ln = l[-1], len(l) - 1
    for j in range(ln):
        yield l[(i + j) % ln]
    yield i
```

Output:

```
In [2]: l = [2, 19, 6, 26, 1, 15, 12, 3]

In [3]: list(swap(l))
Out[3]: [26, 1, 15, 12, 2, 19, 6, 3]
```

Or using a `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque
def swap(l):
    ln, deq = len(l) - 1, deque(l)
    i = deq.pop()
    deq.rotate(ln - i), deq.append(i)
    return deq
```

A more condensed version but uses more memory:

```
def swap(l):
    i, ln = l[-1], len(l) - 1
    return [l[(i + j)% ln] for j in range(ln)] + [i]
```

Not sure what should happen if the last number is > the length of the list, using modulo will mean cycling the list where slicing will grow you list adding repeated elements, you may want to handle that case specifically.

Comment: Ive tried the suggestions you guys gave but to no avail. I need to mutate the list. So far I have insert_top_to_bottom([1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26])
[23, 26, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]

Comment: so I just need to get the 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,2,5,8,11,14,17,20 in front of the 26

Comment: @vig143, you mean mutate the original list? All my examples give you your expected output, if you want to mutate the original list use `my_list[:] = swap(my_list)`

Comment: If you are going to be doing this a lot just use a deque all the time then you can do  it all inplace efficiently and easily